# Copy a single dependency jar into a folder via build.sbt

Tags: scala, jar, build, sbt, newrelic

During the `stage` task, I'd like `sbt` to grab the **newrelic** jar from the **ivy** repos and copy it into a folder. Ideally, the jar is configured the same way dependencies are, but not necessarily within the `libraryDependencies` `Seq` itself (as it's not a build or runtime dependency).

Comment: To which folder should the jar be copied? Should it be inside the project?

Comment: Yup! I'd like to just copy it into a folder called **newrelic** right at the root of the project. The folder will already exist (as it will contain ```newrelic.yml``` which will persist in the source code repos (I don't want to store the jar in with source code, though).

Answer (score 4):

You could declare a new configuration `Stage`. You could set `libraryDependencies` to the desired value in that configuration. Later your `stage` task could read update report and copy the files to the desired directory.

```
val stage = taskKey[Unit]("Stage task")

val Stage = config("stage")

val root = project.in(file(".")).configs(Stage).settings( inConfig(Stage)(Classpaths.ivyBaseSettings): _* )

libraryDependencies in Stage := Seq("com.newrelic.agent.java" % "newrelic-api" % "3.7.0")

stage := {
  (update in Stage).value.allFiles.foreach { f =>
    IO.copyFile(f, baseDirectory.value / f.getName)
  }
}
```

You can checkout a working example [in my github repository](https://github.com/lpiepiora/stack-overflow/tree/master/solutions/q-24024866)

Comment: Thanks for this. Getting a compilation error - which is confusing to me because according to the sbt docs, this val is supposed to exist:

```
[error] /Users/bloo/Workspace/myapp/project/Build.scala:11: value ivyBaseSettings is not a member of object sbt.Classpaths
[error]     val root = project.in(file(".")).configs(NewRelic).settings(inConfig(NewRelic)(Classpaths.ivyBaseSettings): _*)
```

Comment: Are you using sbt 0.13.5 ?

Comment: @bloo just a note, if you're using older version of sbt you very likely will have to use `Classpaths.baseSettings` instead of `Classpaths.ivyBaseSettings`

Comment: Unfortunately, when I apply this snippet to my larger build.sbt file with significantly larger set of `libraryDependencies`, the `stage` task will copy all jars of all those other, global dependencies to the target directory, and newrelic-api.jar will NOT be included with them. Seems like `libraryDependencies in Stage` doesn't sufficiently separate the dependencies for this task from other dependencies.