# Why scalaInstance is different from scalaVersion in sbt?

Tags: sbt

build.sbt

```
val Backend = config("backend")

inConfig(Backend)(Defaults.configSettings)

scalaVersion in Backend := "2.11.2-SNAPSHOT"
```

sbt repl:

```
> show backend:scalaInstance
[info] Scala instance{version label 2.10.4, actual version 2.10.4, library jar: /home/masgui/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar, compiler jar: /home/masgui/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-compiler.jar}

> backend:scalaVersion
[info] 2.11.2-SNAPSHOT
```

current work arround:

```
lazy val v = Project(
    id = "a",
    base = file("woot"),
    settings = Project.defaultSettings ++ Seq(
        offline := true,
        scalaVersion := "2.11.2-SNAPSHOT"
    )
)

// ...
scalaInstance in (Backend, Revolver.reStart) := (scalaInstance in v).value
```

**edit**

When i add `Classpaths.ivyBaseSettings` to Backend it ignores `ivyConfigurations += Backend`

```
> show ivyConfigurations
[info] List(..., backend)
```

but

```
> backend:update
Cannot add dependency 'com.scalakata#backend_2.11;0.1-20140706T182100' to configuration 'backend' of module com.scalakata#plugin;0.1-20140709T150113 because this configuration doesn't exist!
```

**edit**
I solved this with one of your previous awnser: [Copy a single dependency jar into a folder via build.sbt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24024866/copy-a-single-dependency-jar-into-a-folder-via-build-sbt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR;

You have to also add `Classpaths.ivyBaseSettings`, `Classpaths.jvmBaseSettings` and `Defaults.compileBase`  to your `Backend` configuration.

#### build.sbt

```
val Backend = config("backend") 

inConfig(Backend)(Classpaths.ivyBaseSettings ++ Classpaths.jvmBaseSettings ++ Defaults.compileBase ++ Defaults.configSettings)

scalaVersion in Backend := "2.11.1"
```

### Longer Version

The task `scalaInstance` is undefined in your `Backend` config, so sbt delegates to default `scalaInstance`.

```
[info] Delegates:
[info]  backend:scalaInstance
[info]  *:scalaInstance
[info]  {.}/backend:scalaInstance
[info]  {.}/*:scalaInstance
[info]  */backend:scalaInstance
[info]  */*:scalaInstance
```

If you check where it's defined, you can see it's in `*:scalaInstance`

```
> inspect definitions scalaInstance
[info] 
[info]  *:scalaInstance
```

If you want it to be defined you have to add `Defaults.compileBase` to your `Backend` configuration.

You can confirm it's not defined in the `Backend` scope.

```
> inspect definitions scalaInstance
[info] 
[info]  *:scalaInstance
[info]  backend:scalaInstance
```

But that's not enough, if you check the output of the `show backend:scalaInstance`, you'll see that it's still `2.10.x`.

```
> show backend:scalaInstance
[info] Scala instance{version label 2.11.1, actual version 2.10.4, library jar: /home/lpiepiora/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-library.jar, compiler jar: /home/lpiepiora/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.4/lib/scala-compiler.jar}
```

We need to configure the right classpath, by adding `Classpaths.ivyBaseSettings ++ Classpaths.jvmBaseSettings`.

The `show backend:scalaInstance` shows the right version.

```
> show backend:scalaInstance
[info] Scala instance{version label 2.11.1, actual version 2.11.1, library jar: /home/lpiepiora/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.1.jar, compiler jar: /home/lpiepiora/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar}
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed 08-Jul-2014 20:32:18
```